# C# Safe File Parsing / Parsing Strategy

Tags: c#, parsing

This is probably a newbie question:

What is the smartest way to parse a texfile if looks like this:

```
material polygon name
0
0
9
            -7          4.5         0
            -7          9.166667            0
            -2.333333           4.5         0
```

I am only interested in the 9 xyz values. However, I dont know a safe way to filter them out because sometimes the information is writen in one single line like this:

```
material polygon name 0 0 9 -7 4.5 0 -7 9.166667 0 -2.333333 4.5 0
```

Sometimes it is delimited with a whitespace, sometimes with tabs.
I guess the `0 0 9` indicates that there are 9 values following. 
So far Ive only learned parsing TXT files with the `.Split(' ')`

```
            System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(_file);
            string ln = reader.ReadLine();

            while (ln != null)
            {
                if (ln != null && ln[0] != '#')
                {
                    string[] lnsplit = ln.Split(' ');
                    double X = lnsplit[bla];
                    double Y = lnsplit[bla+1];
                    double Z = lnsplit[bla+2];
                }
                ln = occreader.ReadLine();
            }
            occreader.Close();
```

But this does of course only work if the file is strictly structured.

Answer (score 1):

I would use regular expressions with `RegexOptions.SingleLine` enabled. Something like
`^material polygon name (?:\d\s*){3}(?:(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*){9}$`

The `\s` operator covers multiple lines, and you can use the resulting `Match` object to pull out the nine values you want. (from the `Captures` property of `Groups[1]`.

Comment: "*repeat that last part nine times*"? DRY applies to regular expressions too. Use `pattern{x}`, or `pattern{x,y}`. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

Comment: hmm.. regex seems to be the way to go... can you explain how to define a pattern a bit better? how can I define a pattern like: string string string int int int 9xdouble ? thanks a lot in advance

Comment: @timkado see the link in my comment and have fun. There's a whole site dedicated to regexes: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ Also, give Regex Coach a try, it's a wonderful piece of software.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression that matches floating point numbers, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154621/regular-expression-a-line-of-string-contains-only-float-numbers-and-tab-spaces) for instance.
Then just call Regex.Match and skip the first three matches.